# Gzip Json request

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, gzip

Hi I have following type of json object with lot of files and stuff being uploaded in one request from android,Number of pictures may vary and can be more than the following example. There is also lot of other small key values like address,phone etc going on the example

```
   {
        "pdf": "base64stringvalue",
        "name": "username",
        "picture": "base64string",
        "picture1": "base64string",
        "picture2": "base64string",
        "picture3": "base64string",
        "picture4": "base64string",
        "picture5": "base64string",
        "picture6": "base64string",
        "picture7": "base64string",
        "picture8": "base64string",
        "picture9": "base64string"
    }
```

i want to gZip the object and was wondering what would be the best way to do so,based on using gzip resources once(a) and multiple times (b)

(a)should i gzip compress whole json object on the client & decompress it on the server

```
{"object":"gzipped(wholeObject)"}
```

(b) Should i gzip only the base64string values in the object ( basically compressing and decompressing each entity seperately) and something like this

```
{
    "pdf": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "name": "username",
    "picture": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture1": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture2": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture3": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture4": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture5": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture6": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture7": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture8": "gzipped(base64string)",
    "picture9": "gzipped(base64string)"
}
```

Comment: What don't you compress it in HTTP level. Just post your data as compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gzip, larger is the datas, better is the compression.

To understand how it works, you may want to read [details about gzip algorithm](http://www.infinitepartitions.com/art001.html).

So the best solution would be :

```
{"object":"gzipped(wholeObject)"}
```

But the best would be to compress the value before sending it through HTTP. To do that, just in your request, set that you accept Gzip with :

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

And in your response, tell that it's GZip encoded with :

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

More informations about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).